# deleting object allocated with a custom new operator

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm writing a stack based allocator for STL. The idea is to allocate a big chunk of memory once and let it build up while objects are constructed and then reset it to zero when needed. For example, this could be used for storing level information for a game or for objects that are created for a single iteration of a game loop. When you load a level you build up the stack, when you need to load a new a level you just reset the top pointer to the beginning, no OS calls needed.

Now my issue is the way the standard allocator does things, namely the `deallocate()` function. In [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/deallocate/) article i can read that

> In the default allocator, the block of storage is deallocated using
>   ::operator delete.

which implies that by using the `deallocate()` function both the memory is freed and the destructor is called. Now for the purpouse of my allocator i can make the `deallocate()` function to be empty, since i'm not going to deallocate memory for individual objects.

So, the question is, **how do the STL containers use the allocator class to create new objects? Since the default allocator uses `new` and `delete`, do the containers ever call `construct()` or `destroy()`?** Should i make my `deallocate()` function also call the descrutor?

I guess the same question goes for the `allocate()` and `construct()` methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> which implies that by using the deallocate() function both the memory
>   is freed and the destructor is called

No it doesn't. `::operator delete` is the global delete function, it just frees the memory. The `delete` operator is a different thing, despite the similarity of name -- it destructs and then calls a delete function (either the global delete function or an overload).

The destructor is called by the `destroy` function of the allocator.

Standard containers use `allocate` to get some memory, then `construct` if and when they need that memory to contain an element, `destroy` if and only if they `construct`ed, and `deallocate` to free the memory. For example:

```
{
    std::vector<int> v; // may or may not call anything on the allocator
    v.reserve(10000); // calls 'allocate'
    v.resize(100); // calls 'construct' 100 times
    v.resize(50); // calls 'destroy' 50 times
} // destructor calls 'destroy' 50 times and then 'deallocate'
```